# (spark-xml) Receiving only null when parsing xml column using from_xml function

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, apache-spark-xml

I'm trying to parse a very simple XML string column using spark-xml, but I only manage to receive `null` values, even when the XML is correctly populated.

The XSD that I'm using to parse the xml is:

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="from"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="to"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="message"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

While the XML in the column present as string is as below, with every tag correctly populated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <message>Remember me this weekend</message>
</note>
```

My spark code written in scala is something like this:

```scala
    // XML Schema
    val schema = XSDToSchema.read("<the XSD as string>")
    
    // Spark Structured Streaming (N.b. the column value contains the xml as string)
    import spark.implicits._
    var df = initSource(spark)
      .withColumn("parsed", from_xml($"value", schema, 
          Map(
              "mode" -> "FAILFAST",
              "nullValue"-> "",
              "rowTag" -> "note",
              "ignoreSurroundingSpaces" -> "true"
          )
      ))
      .select($"value",$"parsed.note.from", $"parsed.note.to", $"parsed.note.message")
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      // .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      // .option("nullValue", "")
      // .option("rowTag", "note")
      // .option("ignoreSurroundingSpaces","true")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination(30*1000)
```

Printing the schema of this dataFrame (before the select statement) would give the expected schema

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parsed: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- note: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- to: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- message: string (nullable = false)
```

But when printing in console the result, all I get are `null` values like below:

```
....
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+----+----+-------+
|               value|from|  to|message|
+--------------------+----+----+-------+
|<?xml version="1....|null|null|   null|
|<?xml version="1....|null|null|   null|
|<?xml version="1....|null|null|   null|
....
```

I don't think it is relevant but the source of this xml column is from reading a Kafka topic defined as below:

```scala
    def initSource(spark: SparkSession) : DataFrame = {
        spark.readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("startingoffsets", "earliest")
          .option("subscribe", "my-test-topic")
          .load()
          .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    }
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem and solved it? I'm running out of options, I would really appreciate a hint on this :)

The version of spark-xml I'm using is the latest one atm, `0.12.0` with spark `3.1.1`.

### Update

I was passing the spark-xml options wrongly after calling `writeStream`, instead they need to be passed as a 3rd parameter of the `from_xml` function. I still get only null values tho...

Comment: this is not an answer: firstly replace `awaitTermination(30*1000)` with `awaitTermination()` other wise your query will stop in 30 seconds. Replace `.outputMode("append")` to `.outputMode("update")` to see only new updated rows per batch. Next try .foreachbatch writer and check the output of 1 dataframe. if that also contains null, because if that's the case then there is some mapping error of the actual XML data to the provided schema

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ChitralVerma , I had put those options deliberately to process the same data in every execution and terminate the stream after it, since I'm just testing atm, unfortunately I don't see anything wrong with the XML and there is no log  indicating a malformed XML.

Comment: malformed errors will not be in the logs.

Comment: Actually I think they do appear, and if you increase the log level by adding `log4j.logger.com.databricks.spark=DEBUG` in the log4j.properties you can get more detail This is an example of what I get:
`2021-05-17 12:32:11 WARN  com.databricks.spark.xml.parsers.StaxXmlParser$:112 - Dropping malformed line: <?xml versi...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end what opened my eyes was reading the part of the spark-xml [documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#features) that mentions:

> Path to an XSD file that is used to validate the XML *for each row individually*

This mean that the schema matching is done through each row and not through the entire XML, in that case the schema for my example needs to be something like the following:

```scala
val schema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("from", StringType, nullable = true),
        StructField("to", StringType, nullable = true),
        StructField("message", StringType, nullable = true)))
```

and it can also be done using the XSD:

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="from"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="to"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="message"/>
</xs:schema>
```

These two approaches for declaring the schema did the trick for me. Hope it helps to someone in the future.

Comment: Helpful in deed! I was wondering how to extract the row schema from a given XSD defining a document schema, so I raised this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596525/extracting-row-tag-schema-from-structtype-in-scala-to-parse-nested-xml