# Extracting row tag schema from StructType in Scala to parse nested XML

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xsd, databricks

I'm trying to parse a wide, nested XML file into a DataFrame using the spark-xml library.

Here is an abbreviated schema definition (XSD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="ItemExport">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="Item">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ITEM_ID" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element name="CONTEXT" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:string" />
                ...
                <xs:element name="CLASSIFICATIONS">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CLASSIFICATION">
                            <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="CLASS_SCHEME" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="CLASS_LEVEL" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="CLASS_CODE" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="CLASS_CODE_NAME" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="EFFECTIVE_FROM" type="xs:dateTime" />
                                <xs:element name="EFFECTIVE_TO" type="xs:dateTime" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML file containing the data would looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemExport>
    <TIMEZONE>PT</TIMEZONE>
    <Item>
        <ITEM_ID>56</ITEM_ID>
        <CONTEXT>Sample</CONTEXT>
        <TYPE>Product</TYPE>
    </Item>
    ...
    <Item>
        <ITEM_ID>763</ITEM_ID>
        <CONTEXT>Sample</CONTEXT>
        <TYPE>Product</TYPE>
        <CLASSIFICATIONS>
            <CLASSIFICATION>
                <CLASS_SCHEME>AAU</CLASS_SCHEME>
                <CLASS_LEVEL>1</CLASS_LEVEL>
                <CLASS_CODE>14</CLASS_CODE>
                <CLASS_CODE_NAME>BizDev</CLASS_CODE_NAME>
                <EFFECTIVE_FROM />
                <EFFECTIVE_TO />
            </CLASSIFICATION>
        </CLASSIFICATIONS>
    </Item>
<ItemExport>
```

Now, what's clear is that the `RowTag` needs to be `Item`, but I've encountered an issue regarding the XSD. The row schema is encapsulated within the document schema.

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
import com.databricks.spark.xml._
import java.nio.file.Paths
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val inputFile = "dbfs:/samples/ItemExport.xml"
val schema = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("/dbfs/samples/ItemExport.xsd"))
val df1 = spark.read.option("rowTag", "Item").xml(inputFile)
val df2 = spark.read.schema(schema).xml(inputFile)
```

I basically want to get the `struct` under Item under the root element, not the entire document schema.

```
schema.printTreeString

root
|-- ItemExport: struct (nullable = false)
|    |-- Item: struct (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- ITEM_ID: integer (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- CONTEXT: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |-- TYPE: string (nullable = false)
...(a few more fields...)
|    |    |-- CLASSIFICATIONS: struct (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |-- CLASSIFICATION: array (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- CLASS_SCHEME: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- CLASS_LEVEL: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE_NAME: string (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_FROM: timestamp (nullable = false)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_TO: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

In the case above, parsing with the document schema yields an empty DataFrame:

```
df2.show()

+-----------+
| ItemExport|
+-----------+
+-----------+
```

while the inferred schema is basically correct, but it can only infer nested columns when they are present (which is not always the case):

```
df1.show()

+----------+--------------------+----------+---------------+
|   ITEM_ID|             CONTEXT|      TYPE|CLASSIFICATIONS|
+----------+--------------------+----------+---------------+
|        56|            Sample  |   Product|         {null}|
|        57|            Sample  |   Product|         {null}|
|        59|              Part  | Component|         {null}|
|        60|              Part  | Component|         {null}|
|        61|            Sample  |   Product|         {null}|
|        62|            Sample  |   Product|         {null}|
|        63|          Assembly  |   Product|         {null}|

df1.printSchema

root
|-- ITEM_ID: long (nullable = true)
|-- CONTEXT: string (nullable = false)
|-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
...
|-- CLASSIFICATIONS: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- CLASSIFICATION: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE_NAME: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- CLASS_LEVEL: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- CLASS_SCHEME: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_FROM: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_TO: string (nullable = true)
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531343/spark-xml-receiving-only-null-when-parsing-xml-column-using-from-xml-function) and in the [XML library docs](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#features) ("Path to an XSD file that is used to validate the XML for each row individually"), I can parse into a given row-level schema as such:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val structschema = StructType(
  Array(
    StructField("ITEM_ID",IntegerType,false), 
    StructField("CONTEXT",StringType,false), 
    StructField("TYPE",StringType,false),
  )
)

val df_struct = spark.read.schema(structschema).option("rowTag", "Item").xml(inputFile)
```

I'd like to obtain the schema for the nested columns from the XSD however. How to go about this given the `schema`?

Version info: Scala `2.12`, Spark `3.1.1`, spark-xml `0.12.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns in XSD are required or not null & Some of the columns in XML file is null to match XSD  & XML file content, change schema from `nullable=false` to `nullable=true`

Try following code.

```
  import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
  import com.databricks.spark.xml._
  import java.nio.file.Paths
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

```
  val inputFile = "dbfs:/samples/ItemExport.xml"
```

Getting schema from XSD, Applying same schema to an empty dataframe to get required columns.

```
 val schema = spark
    .createDataFrame(
      spark
        .sparkContext
        .emptyRDD[Row],
      XSDToSchema
        .read(Paths.get("/dbfs/samples/ItemExport.xsd"))
    )
    .select("ItemExport.Item.*")
    .schema
```

```
  val df2 = spark.read
    .option("rootTag", "ItemExport")
    .option("rowTag", "Item")
    .schema(setNullable(schema, true)) // To match XSD & XML file content setting all columns are optional i.e nullable=true
    .xml(inputFile)
```

Below function will change all columns `optional` or `nullable=true`

```
  def setNullable(schema: StructType, nullable:Boolean = false): StructType = {
    def recurNullable(schema: StructType): Seq[StructField] =
      schema.fields.map{
        case StructField(name, dtype: StructType, _, meta) =>
          StructField(name, StructType(recurNullable(dtype)), nullable, meta)
        case StructField(name, dtype: ArrayType, _, meta) => dtype.elementType match {
          case struct: StructType => StructField(name, ArrayType(StructType(recurNullable(struct)), true), nullable, meta)
          case other => StructField(name, other, nullable, meta)
        }
        case StructField(name, dtype, _, meta) =>
          StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta)
      }

    StructType(recurNullable(schema))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531343/spark-xml-receiving-only-null-when-parsing-xml-column-using-from-xml-function) a bit useful! :).

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I've noticed that in your case you could also let spark-xml infer the schema from the xml.

By using this xml as example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ItemExport>
    <TIMEZONE>PT</TIMEZONE>
    <Item>
        <ITEM_ID>56</ITEM_ID>
        <CONTEXT>Sample</CONTEXT>
        <TYPE>Product</TYPE>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ITEM_ID>763</ITEM_ID>
        <CONTEXT>Sample763</CONTEXT>
        <TYPE>Product2</TYPE>
        <CLASSIFICATIONS>
            <CLASSIFICATION>
                <CLASS_SCHEME>AAU</CLASS_SCHEME>
                <CLASS_LEVEL>1</CLASS_LEVEL>
                <CLASS_CODE>14</CLASS_CODE>
                <CLASS_CODE_NAME>BizDev</CLASS_CODE_NAME>
                <EFFECTIVE_FROM/>
                <EFFECTIVE_TO/>
            </CLASSIFICATION>
            <CLASSIFICATION>
                <CLASS_SCHEME>AXU</CLASS_SCHEME>
                <CLASS_LEVEL>2</CLASS_LEVEL>
                <CLASS_CODE>16</CLASS_CODE>
                <CLASS_CODE_NAME>BizProd</CLASS_CODE_NAME>
                <EFFECTIVE_FROM/>
                <EFFECTIVE_TO/>
            </CLASSIFICATION>
        </CLASSIFICATIONS>
    </Item>
</ItemExport>
```

And this spark code snippet,

```scala
var df = spark.read
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("rootTag", "ItemExport")
      .option("rowTag", "Item")
      .option("ignoreSurroundingSpaces","true")
//      .schema(schema)
      .xml("pathTo/testing.xml")
      .selectExpr("*")


    df.printSchema()

    df.show()
```

I got the following schema:

```
 |-- CLASSIFICATIONS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CLASSIFICATION: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CLASS_CODE_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CLASS_LEVEL: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CLASS_SCHEME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_FROM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- EFFECTIVE_TO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTEXT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ITEM_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
```

It also seems to work with the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="ITEM_ID" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="CONTEXT" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CLASSIFICATIONS">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CLASSIFICATION">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="CLASS_SCHEME" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="CLASS_LEVEL" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="CLASS_CODE" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="CLASS_CODE_NAME" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EFFECTIVE_FROM" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EFFECTIVE_TO" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And if you want to get the nested CLASSIFICATION rows as actual rows in your dataframe, it seems you can opt to use the `explode_outer` function (not sure about the impact of performance/memory-usage on this)
So you could do something like the following:

```scala
    // Starting transformation
    import spark.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode_outer
    var df = spark.read
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("rootTag", "ItemExport")
      .option("rowTag", "Item")
      .option("ignoreSurroundingSpaces","true")
      .schema(schema) // notice I'm using the XSD this time :)
      .xml("pathTo/testing.xml")
      .select($"ITEM_ID", $"CONTEXT", $"TYPE", explode_outer($"CLASSIFICATIONS.CLASSIFICATION"))
      .select($"ITEM_ID", $"CONTEXT", $"TYPE",
          $"col.CLASS_SCHEME", $"col.CLASS_LEVEL", $"col.CLASS_CODE", $"col.CLASS_CODE_NAME",  $"col.EFFECTIVE_FROM", $"col.EFFECTIVE_TO")

    df.printSchema()

    df.show()
```

In this case my DataFrame shows the results below

```
+-------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+
|ITEM_ID|  CONTEXT|    TYPE|CLASS_SCHEME|CLASS_LEVEL|CLASS_CODE|CLASS_CODE_NAME|EFFECTIVE_FROM|EFFECTIVE_TO|
+-------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+
|     56|   Sample| Product|        null|       null|      null|           null|          null|        null|
|    763|Sample763|Product2|         AAU|          1|        14|         BizDev|          null|        null|
|    763|Sample763|Product2|         AXU|          2|        16|        BizProd|          null|        null|
+-------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+
```

I hope this can somehow help in your use case.

#### Update

I modified the XSD, the minOccurs="0" to make parameters optional, are only needed in the fields that seem to be missing according to the XML you provided as example, these are (CLASSIFICATIONS, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO)

Comment: Yeah, the explode thing is the end goal so thanks for sharing it and the `minOccurs=0` in the schema is pretty relevant - which I guess translates into `nullable=true` for a `StructField`. But you did have to change the XSD unfortunately, which is what I was looking to do programmatically (see answer with emptyRDD and `select("ItemExport.Item.*")` )

Comment: Oh sorry @HendrikF, I think I misunderstood the question :)... it's great you got the answer! ^^

Comment: No worries, still useful info!